# Interrupting a connecting windows wsa socket

Tags: windows, sockets, msdn

I was just wondering if it is possible to interrupt call to windows socket "connect" function?

The problem is that my code requires that to be done in a different thread (so GUI thread keeps running). But when the programm is closed there my still be threads calling "connect" that are wating for a WSAETIMEDOUT exception.

Any ideas?

Update/Hint: i cant call close() since i only have a valid handle when connect() returns. the latter one is not the case when using blocking sockets and having a tcp-connect to a firewalled location (for example) :/

Answer (score 0):

If the socket is in blocking mode, the only way to abort `connect()` call is to close the socket from a different thread context than the one that is calling `connect()`.  `connect()` will return an error, and the thread can then exit itself normally.

If the socket is in non-blocking or overlapped mode, `connect()` will return immediately with a `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error, and you then have to call `select()`, `WSAAsyncSelect(FD_CONNECT)`, or `WSAEventSelect(FD_CONNECT)` to detect when the connection has been established before continuing with your socket work.  Since the calling thread is not blocked on `connect()`, it is free to periodically check for any termination/abort signals from the rest of your code, and if detected then close the socket (if needed) and exit itself normally.

If you write your socket code in non-blocking or overlapped mode, then you do not really need to use a thread.  You can do your socket work within the main thread without blocking your UI, then you can just close the socket when needed.  It takes a little more work to code that way, but it does work.  Or you can continue using a thread.  It will keep your socket code separate from your UI code and thus a bit more managable.

Comment: theres one big problem, i cant call close(<HANDLE>) since i dont hav any handle to operate on. i will only have this handle when the initial socket connect() call has terminated.

so its a chicken-egg problem here

Comment: You close the handle that was returned by `socket()`.  `connect()` takes an existing socket handle as input.  It does not return a new socket handle. So just make sure you store the socket handle from `socket()` in a place that both the connecting thread and the closing thread can reach.